# Android NDK gdb (ndk-gdb) exit with error readchar: Got EOF when use "info functions"

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk, gdb, gdbserver

I got very strange issue with ndk-gdb.

When I try to user comands like: break < fun_name >, break < file_name:line >, info functions I got error and gdb exit:

```
(gdb) b Java_com_rtsoft_shared_AppRenderer_nativeResize
readchar: Got EOF
Remote side has terminated connection.  GDBserver will reopen the connection.
Listening on Unix socket debug-socket
/cygdrive/c/Programs/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-gdb: line 699:  2876 Segmentation fault      $GDBCLIENT -x `native_path $GDBSETUP`
```

Tha poroblem I see this gdb does not see my src files, but why?

"info sharedlib" show my libs loaded and all they have debug symbols.

```
                        No          libwmlscriptcore.so
                        No          libwebcore.so
0x81186590  0x813909a8  Yes         C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.so
0x80cbb5d8  0x80dcbdcc  Yes         C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/obj/local/armeabi/libBullet.so
0x81939240  0x81a49be8  Yes         C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/obj/local/armeabi/libelementaldefence.so
                        No          gralloc.msm7k.so
                        No          libGLES_android.so
                        No          libgsl.so
```

"show dir" show all valid directoryes which contain src files (.c, .cpp).

```
show dir
Source directories searched: C:/Programs/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/Entity;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/GUI;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/Manager;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/Math;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/Renderer;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/Network;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/Audio;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/Renderer/linearparticle/sources;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/Irrlicht;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../project/source;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../project/source/Component;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../project/source/GameObjects;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../project/source/GameObjects/CreepStates;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../project/source/GameObjects/TowerStates;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../project/source/gs;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../project/source/mgr;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../project/source/mgr/CursorActions;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../project/source/mgr/MagicEffects;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../project/source/mgr/MagicEffects/Affectors;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../project/source/utils;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/android;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/util;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/Irrlicht/include;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/Irrlicht/source/Irrlicht;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/Irrlicht/source/Irrlicht/libpng;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/Irrlicht/source/Irrlicht/jpeglib;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/ClanLib-2.0/Sources;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/util/boost;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/memory;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/Bullet;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/pugixml;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/util/unzip;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/util/zlib;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/util/bzip2;C:/Workspace/Irrlicht/ElementDefence/project/android/jni/../../../shared/Irrlicht/irrBullet;C:/Programs/android-ndk-r8b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include;C:/Programs/android-ndk-r8b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/include;$cdir;$cwd
```

When application crash gdb stopped, show stacktrace and react to "c" command, but not show any src files.

When program stopped in Java brakepoint (in Eclipce) I run command below in cygwin shell (with administrator pemission):

`$NDK/ndk-gdb --verbose --force --adb=/cygdrive/c/Programs/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe`

I debug on device. Try use android-ndk-r7-crystax-5.beta2 and android-ndk-r8b. All the same error. Some one have this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I found the reason. LOCAL_CFLAGS have some flags like "-g cgdb" for force debug sumbols. When I delete thsi flags problem was solved.